# Height of Bootstrap's cauousel not responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been working off of [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) example from Bootstrap's website, and I just noticed that the carousel's height doesn't respond to the size of the screen. The width works fine but for some reason not height. I'm wondering what do I have to change for the height of the carousel to decrease as the screen does?

I've tried adding `height: auto;` to the `.carousel` class and removing the carousel controls but that doesn't effect the height.

EDIT
There are fixed heights in the css (below), but changing them to auto simply removes the images and the carousel outline remains the same height.

```
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Hey I've found some fixed heights but I'm not sure if they're the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

edit : and try this

```
.carousel .item {
  max-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the carousel's height remains the same.

Comment: When I add the .carousel .item edit, the images and captions no longer appear and the carousel's height remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway:) I suppose this is the problem with working off Bootstrap's examples and not writing it from scratch yourself :/

Comment: Hi, you were actually right about there being a fixed height and it was in the code that I saw after your first comment (below); it ensures that the image scales to the height of the carousel so I thought I should leave it, but it also causes the carousel's height to be fixed. I changed the height to 100% and it's now responsive. Thanks for your help  .carousel .item {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
}